# Why does extra kwarg to `create_autospec` not configure the resulting mock?

Tags: python, mocking

In a test suite I have some mocks created by directly calling the `Mock` constructor.
Now I would like to use the `create_autospec` function instead, to gain the additional benefits of autospeccing.
However in one case I encountered unexpected behavior.

Let's assume I have the following minimal class defined, and I want to mock `method` so that it always returns `0`.

```py
class Class:
    def method(self):
        return 1
```

Currently I am mocking the class like this:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

ClassMock = Mock(Class, **{'return_value.method.return_value': 0})
instance = ClassMock()
```

and it works as expected:

```
>>> instance.method()
0
```

However if I mock the class using `create_autospec`:

```py
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

ClassMock = create_autospec(Class, **{'return_value.method.return_value': 0})
instance = ClassMock()
```

the method's return value is not configured:

```
>>> instance.method()
<MagicMock name='mock().method()' id='139993721092192'>
```

This seems unexpected to me, because according to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.create_autospec),

> `create_autospec()` also takes arbitrary keyword arguments that are passed to the constructor of the created mock.

So my question is whether I'm missing something or the behavior in this case is not consistent with the documentation.

**Edit 1:**

As @wim points out in the comments, when mocking a class, its `return_value` attribute is explicitly overwritten by a recursive call to `create_autospec`.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2644

This is probably the reason of the above described behavior.

**Edit 2:**

I also tried to create the instance directly by setting `instance=True` but this doesn't work either.

```
>>> instance = create_autospec(Class, instance=True, **{'method.return_value': 0})
>>> instance.method()
<MagicMock name='mock.method()' id='140603529804824'>
```

First, the mocked method's return value is configured correctly here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L622

but then it's overwritten by a new mock object when applying the class' spec here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2695

Comment: This seems to be a bug in `mock`.  I think it overwrites the return_value here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2667-L2669

Comment: @wim Thanks, that would explain it. I updated the question.